# The slider does not move after pausing the player MediaSession Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-service, playback, android-mediasession

```
public class MediaService extends Service {
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    ScheduledExecutorService timer;
    public static Intent playPauseIntent, nextMusicIntent, prevMusicIntent;

    MediaSessionCompat  mediaSession;

    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();

    final PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                            | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                            | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                            | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                            | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
                            | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
                            | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO);

    Drawable drawablePausePlay;


    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public MediaService() {
    }

    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        MediaService getService() {
            return MediaService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder binder = new MusicBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplication(), "TAG");
        mediaSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
                        | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) pos);
                    FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.setProgress((int)pos);
                    updateMediaPlaybackState((int) pos, PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING);
                    Log.d("qwerty","seek");
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) playOrPause();
                }
            }
        });

        mediaSession.setActive(true);

        drawablePausePlay = getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_play_notif);
        playPauseIntent = new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
        playPauseIntent.setAction("PlayPause");
        nextMusicIntent = new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
        nextMusicIntent.setAction("NextMusic");
        prevMusicIntent = new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
        prevMusicIntent.setAction("PrevMusic");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null)
        {
            switch (intent.getAction().toString())
            {
                case "PlayPause" : playOrPause(); break;
                case "NextMusic" : changeMusic(1); break;
                case "PrevMusic" : changeMusic(-1); break;
            }
        }


        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public void updateDataMusic(ItemMusic music) {
        if (music.getImage() != null)
        {
            if(music.getImage() == MainActivity.defaultIcon) FragmentPlayer.playerLayout.setBackground(getApplication().getDrawable(R.color.border_black_medium));
            else FragmentPlayer.playerLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(MainActivity.BlurImage(music.getImage(),getApplication())));
        }
        else
        {
            music.setImage(MainActivity.defaultIcon);
            FragmentPlayer.playerLayout.setBackground(getApplication().getDrawable(R.color.border_black_medium));
        }

        MainActivity.adapterMusic.notifyDataSetChanged();

        MainActivity.tvCurTitle.setText(music.getTitle());
        MainActivity.ivCurMusic.setImageBitmap(music.getImage());
        FragmentPlayer.imageMusic.setImageBitmap(music.getImage());
        FragmentPlayer.tvTitle.setText(music.getTitle());
        FragmentPlayer.tvAuthor.setText(music.getAuthor());
        FragmentPlayer.tvTotalTime.setText(MainActivity.convertToMMSS(music.getDuration()));
        FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);


    }



    public Notification createNotification(Context context, ItemMusic music, int iconPlayPause) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



        // Создание PendingIntents для действий кнопок.
        PendingIntent piPlayPause = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, playPauseIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // PendingIntent для Play/Pause
        PendingIntent piNext = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, nextMusicIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);; // PendingIntent для Next
        PendingIntent piPrevious = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, prevMusicIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);; // PendingIntent для Previous

        // Создание канала уведомления для Android O и выше
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "CHANNEL_ID", "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }



        metadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, mediaPlayer.getDuration());



        mediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());

        mediaSession.setActive(true);

        // Создание билдера уведомлений
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_music_select) // Иконка уведомления
                .setContentTitle(music.getTitle()) // Название трека
                .setContentText(music.getAuthor()) // Исполнитель
                .setLargeIcon(music.getImage()) // Обложка альбома
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true) // Не обновлять при изменении
                .setShowWhen(false) // Не показывать время уведомления
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_left_notif, "Previous", piPrevious) // Кнопка пред. трека
                .addAction(iconPlayPause, "PlayPause", piPlayPause) // Кнопка плей/пауза
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_right_notif, "Next", piNext) // Кнопка след. трека
                .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()));

        // Запуск уведомления
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        return notification;
    }

    public void updateMediaPlaybackState(long currentPos, int currentState) {
        stateBuilder
                .setState(
                        currentState,
                        currentPos,
                        1.0F
                )
                .setBufferedPosition(currentPos);
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
    }

    @SuppressLint("ForegroundServiceType")
    public void playOrPause() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                FragmentPlayer.ibPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
                FragmentPlayer.plate.clearAnimation();

                startForeground(1,  createNotification(getApplication(),MainActivity.musics.get(MainActivity.currentIndexMusic), R.drawable.icon_stop_notif));
                updateMediaPlaybackState(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED);
                Log.d("qwerty","pause");
                timer.shutdown();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                FragmentPlayer.ibPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                FragmentPlayer.plate.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_plate));
                updateMediaPlaybackState(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(),PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING);
                startForeground(1,  createNotification(getApplication(),MainActivity.musics.get(MainActivity.currentIndexMusic),  R.drawable.icon_play_notif));
                Log.d("qwerty",mediaSession.getController().getPlaybackState().toString());
                timer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.isPressed()) {
                            FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

                        }
                    }
                }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), mediaSession.getController().getPlaybackState().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void createMediaPlayer(String path){
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build()
        );
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    changeMusic(1);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e){
        }
        updateMediaPlaybackState(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(),PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING);
    }

    public void changeMusic(int dif) {
        if (MainActivity.currentIndexMusic == -1) return;
        MainActivity.currentIndexMusic += dif;

        if (MainActivity.currentIndexMusic < 0 || MainActivity.currentIndexMusic > MainActivity.musics.size() - 1 ) MainActivity.currentIndexMusic = 0;

        ItemMusic music = MainActivity.musics.get(MainActivity.currentIndexMusic);
        updateDataMusic(music);
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        createMediaPlayer(music.getPath());
        FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.setMax(MediaService.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        updateMediaPlaybackState(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING);
        playOrPause();
    }


    public void updatePlayingTime(){
        if (mediaPlayer != null) FragmentPlayer.tvCurrentTime.setText(MainActivity.convertToMMSS(String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition())));
    }

    public void seekMediaPlayer(){
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.getProgress());
            updateMediaPlaybackState(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(),PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING);
        }
    }

    public void releaseMediaPlayer(){
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.shutdown();
        }
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaSession.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.setMax(100);
        FragmentPlayer.seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaSession.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }


}
```

I'm asking a question with a translator, so I'm sorry for the spelling. I am creating a music player application and notifications for it. I searched for a long time how to add a slider to the notification and such an error came out that when I pause the player and turn it on again, the slider in the notification stops moving, otherwise everything works. Thank you in advance for your help!
Задаю вопрос с переводчиком так что за орфографию извините. Я создаю приложение музыкальный плеер  а также для него уведомления долго рыскал как добавить к уведомлению ползунок и вылезла такая ошибка что когда я ставлю плеер на паузу и снова его включаю ползунок в уведомлении перестает двигаться в остальном все работает. Заранее благодарю за помощь!